# protractor-http-mock cant find element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, mocking, protractor

I am trying to mock a http request of our angular app with protractor and 
`protractor-http-mock`. My protractor spec file looks like this:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    mock(['bank']);
    browser.get(this.createUrl());
  });

  afterEach(function(){
        mock.teardown();
});
```

My `bank.js` file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  request: {
    path: '/api/v0/bank/demo',
    method: 'GET'
  },
  response: {
    ... my json object
  }
};
```

When I run protractor it says:

> Failed: No element found using locator: by.model("bank.model.bic")

but without mocking everything runs successfull.

Comment: My guess is that mock is not setup correctly or JSON you've provided for response does not satisfy requirements, so data does not get displayed. Try to inspect requests first: [protractor-http-mock#inspection](https://github.com/atecarlos/protractor-http-mock#inspection). Is there any condition before `ng-model="bank.model.bic"`?

Comment: Like @MichaelRadionov said, it means indeed that your page isn't (properly) loaded and the element isn't there. Is the page loaded at all, or does it just appear without the proper elements? (Hint: if protractor is going too fast to see it, add browser.sleep(5000) in your test to pause it for 5 seconds)